# I need help understanding this に際しての昂揚はすでに収まり sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of this sentence.  For context I put the whole sentence.

> [数日来]{すうじつらい}の[上京]{じょうきょう}に[際]{さい}しての[昂揚]{こうよう}はすでに[収]{おさ}まり
>   [京一郎]{きょういちろう}の[心]{こころ}は、ひとときの[凪]{なぎ}にあった。

My translation may be wrong but I have roughly translated the first part to mean "a few days since proceeding to the capital".  I have part of the second half translated as "at the time of promotion". But the last part I am unsure of how to interpret it to make sense of the whole sentence instead of just parts of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that first clause breaks down as (数日来の(上京に際しての(昂揚)))はすでに収まり. Which is to say, the main subject of 収まり is 昂揚, a word that usually refers to a feeling of high spirits (excitement, joy, elation), and everything preceding that is describing the 昂揚.

In this case, the 昂揚 is the result of him coming to the capital (上京に際して) and has been continuing for the past few days (数日来). However, the excitement of coming to the capital has now subsided (収まり), and so his mind is in a state of momentary calm (ひとときの凪).

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me. It makes much more sense now. :)